# How to show the error causing the 'There has been a critical error on your website'?

Tags: errors, debug, 500-internal-error, wp-debug

I'm getting the error: 'There has been a critical error on your website. [Learn more about debugging in WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)'.

How do I display which error I'm getting in the frontend?

I have these three lines in my **wp-config.php**-file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

It surprises me that enabling WP_DEBUG, doesn't show it.
I can (however) still find the errors in `/wp-content/debug.log`, - but it's just an extra step in development, having to open that file and find the error.

How do I just get the proper error displayed on the page, - and not hid away in that debug.log-file?

I can see that WP_DEBUG is enabled, since this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( WP_DEBUG);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

... returns: `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh! I found it.

If I did this:

```
phpinfo();
die();
```

Then I could see that 'display errors` was set to off.

So if I added this in the top of my `functions.php`: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, then it started showing the errors.