# Fatal error trace not shown in development setup

Tags: errors, wp-config, fatal-error, wp-debug

I recently re-did my local dev setup and have been seeing these types of fatal error warnings:

```
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.
```

When I disable the "fatal error catcher" of WP like below to get the actual debug trace of the error I am not seeing anything logged or rendered. I am seeing other `error_log(..)` entries appearing in `/wp-content/debug.log`.

wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

From `phpinfo()` it shows `display_errors` as `On` (so not the same issue as in [this questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372620/how-to-show-the-error-causing-the-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-websi)).

How can I get to see the debug trace of those fatal errors?

Comment: have you used a process of elimination to determine which theme/plugin/file it is that's causing it? Have you checked the server level error log rather than the WP specific one at `wp-content/debug.log`? Your host can point you towards it if you're not sure where that is

Comment: @TomJNowell Jep, it's a localhost setup for dev; no logs in my server/host specific log. And I do get e.g. array index offset warnings and other errors into `debug.log` — just the Fatal ones show up nowhere.

Comment: be sure you're checking the PHP log and not the Apache/Nginx log, and that `php.ini` is configured to log to an error log. Also errors don't just randomly occur like this, they always have a cause and pattern, so narrowing it down further will be important

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks, I'm not trying to debug one specific issue, but generally the fact that I don't get traces for these. Often it's using a WP object as Array or other simple mistakes, but without the trace it can be quite a challenge to narrow them down. For `$ php -i` I get  php -i | grep "log"` `error_log => no value => no value` and `log_errors => On => On`, viewing `phpinfo()` output in the project I have `error_log` pointing to the local `/wp-content/debug.log` file of that project.

Comment: then it seems you don't have a PHP error log, and are relying on the WP `debug.log`, which is suboptimal. It means anything that fails before the WP error handler is added is not logged or caught because `content/debug.log` has not been set yet. You also have the problem that if your error reporting level is weird it may not log certain types of error at all. Likewise if you use `@` a lot, `@` does not fix errors, it silences them, the error still happens. I don't think this is necessarily WP specific and you're shooting yourself in the foot by looking only in WP circles. It's generic PHP

Answer (score 0):

Something, I do not know what, is resetting my global `error_reporting(E_ALL)` level to a higher level, thus hiding the errors. Explicitly adding the lower error_reporting in files in question helps show the error.